# How to discard old reactions in a Facebook Live video?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

We've been developing an interactive product for Facebook Live Videos when people can "fight" (i.e. choose between multiple options in things like videogames and so) using reactions.

The problem is that as we have more things than reactions we obviously have to use the same reaction for more than one thing, so old reactions are accumulated and the result is not really accurate. We tried to mitigate this by assigning reactions to the battles in a given order so people must change them through the live streaming, but people who react but then go away leave us with lots of reactions that don´t correspond to the current battles

So, is there any way to discard old reactions? Facebook Graph API only returns the user and the reaction but nothing else like the time or anything that can be used to discard them...

Comment: Hope you have first of all taken https://en.facebookbrand.com/assets/reactions into account ...